# How to solve GSONFormat parse error in android?

Tags: android, json, android-studio, gson

I am parsing one JSON in GSONFormat in Android studio but i am getting parse error.

```
{
  "menu_items": [{
    "0": [],
    "1": [],
    "2": [{
        "keg_id": "4",
        "name": "Abcd",
        "status": 2
    }],
    "3": [{
        "keg_id": "2",
        "name": "Xyz",
        "status": 3
    }]
  }]
}
```

Please kindly go through my above sample JSON and suggest me some solution.

Comment: because your 0 and 1 array are blank and when your code trying to find `keg_id` in 1st array it is not available therefore giving parse error

Comment: @Deeptiman please post your error log

Answer (score 0):

You need to test the length() for your array.

```
item = your_json_object_menu_items.getJSONArray("0");
if(item != null && item.length() > 0 ){
   // do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
class ItemMenu
{
    @SerializedName("keg_id")
    private int keg_id;

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("status")
    private String status;
}
```

And

```
class ResponseGson
{
    @SerializedName("menu_items")
    private List<Map<Integer,ItemMenu>> menu_items;
}
```